# how to change the url of the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I am using asp.net and i have a hyperlink tag like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="BusinessWebSiteHyperLink" runat="server" Text="Hyperlink"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I am adding the address from code behind like this:

```
  DataTable dt = objYPSearchResultsDataAccess.GetYPBusinessListingDetails(businessID);
  BusinessWebSiteHyperLink.Text = dt.Rows[0]["BusinessWebsite"].ToString();
  string Hyperlink = dt.Rows[0]["Hyperlink"].ToString();
  if (Hyperlink == "True")
  {
     BusinessWebSiteHyperLink.NavigateUrl = BusinessWebSiteHyperLink.Text;
  }
 else
  {
     BusinessWebSiteHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "";
  }
```

every thing is fine but when i click the Business url in the page then the page should redirect me to the business website but it is adding localhost/7467567/...../www.stakeoverflow.com. i just want to redirect my page to stakeoverflow when it is clicked. how to solve this?

Comment: what's a typical value in `BusinessWebSiteHyperLink.Text` ?

Comment: for eg. www.stakeoverflow.com it can have

Comment: should that be `www.stackoverflow.com`, or is this a Beef Eater place?

Comment: that should be `www.stakeoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `HTTP` to the front of the url..

```
"http://" + BusinessWebSiteHyperLink.Text
```

Here is my test...

[image]
[image]

when I hover over `test` url, I get...

[image]

When I hover over `test No HTTP`, I get...

[image]

Comment: I have just tested the code, and it works fine...can you post your updated code where you append `http://`